# How to change spinner text color in the actionbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, colors, spinner

in my project I have this custom layout inflated in the actionbar:

[Link to image](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2zfsieh.jpg)

But i would like to have the spinner text of white color.
I've seen a lot of topics on the web about this, but I can't fix the problem yet.
How can I fix this problem? How can I change the text color of my spinner bysetting it to white color?

EDIT:
the xml code of spinner is this:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"></Spinner>
```

It's very simple, I tried many things but nothing..

Comment: I cannot see your image. Please show your spinner XML code.

Comment: Have you tried changing the text color in your custom layout?

Comment: @Kony2013 yes, i tried it but doesn't work

Comment: Do you set the Spinner via XML or via code (programatically)? Have you tried using custom components to populate the Spinner? You should make an XML file specifying it and then via code pass it as argument to the Spinner Adapter.

Comment: Using textColor via XML will have no effect, I regret. You should follow my second suggestion...

Comment: @joaquin can you explain better what I should do?

Comment: See my answer, ask me if I can help you with something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your activity you should have something like this:
(Basically you are getting the Spinner and setting it an adapter. This adapter is the responsible for filling it)

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_spinner_id);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.your_selected_spinner_item, myArrayList<String));

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.your_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And you can have this XMLs: (put them on res/layout)

**your_selected_spinner_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/myLayoutID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

And also
**your_dropdown_item.xml**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/myDropdownLayoutID"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Layout file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_ref_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TextView>
```

Assuming that you are using ArrayAdapter as your Spinner Adapter.

Hope it helps!!!